# Unable to apply CHECK constraint to a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to build a small database schema for student-lab scenario.First I created `classes` table as:

```
CREATE TABLE classes (
    class_id INT NOT NULL,
    class_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (class_id),
    UNIQUE (class_name)
);
```

Then I created `labs` table as:

```
CREATE TABLE labs (
    lab_id INT NOT NULL,
    lab_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    class_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (lab_id),
    UNIQUE (lab_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (class_id) REFERENCES classes (class_id)
);
```

After this I created `students` table as:

```
CREATE TABLE students (
    student_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    student_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    class_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (student_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (class_id) REFERENCES classes (class_id)
);
```

And finally I created `allotments` table to allocate the laboratories for students as:

```
CREATE TABLE allotments (
    student_id INT  NOT NULL,
    lab_id INT NOT NULL,
    day_of_week CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (student_id, lab_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students (student_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (lab_id) REFERENCES labs (lab_id)
);
```

This seems fine. But I want to add a `CHECK` constraint to `allotments` table such that students are allocated to the laboratories of their respective classes only, something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE allotments
ADD CHECK (student_id IN (SELECT student_id
                      FROM students INNER JOIN labs USING (class_id)
                      WHERE students.class_id = labs.class_id));
```

But when I tried this I got the following error message:
`Error Code: 3815. An expression of a check constraint 'allotments_chk_1' contains disallowed function. 0.000 sec`

Please help me with a solution.

Comment: Might not be the problem, but that last , should be a ;

Comment: It's a typo in the last.

Comment: 'Subqueries are not permitted.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html - consider a trigger(s) instead

Comment: It means that I cannot acheive that with a CHECK constraint. I have not started learning triggers yet. This might be the reason to start learning triggers. Thanks @P.Salmon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the idea of @P.Salmon to use a trigger and I found a way to apply the integrity constraint such that a user can only allot a lab to a student only if `student_id` and `lab_id` both belongs to the same class.

Here is the trigger to use:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_allotments_insert
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON allotments FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE students_class_id, labs_class_id INT;
    DECLARE error_message VARCHAR(100);
    SET error_message = CONCAT('Invalid lab_id for student_id ', NEW.student_id);
    SELECT class_id INTO students_class_id
    FROM students
    WHERE student_id = NEW.student_id;
    SELECT class_id INTO labs_class_id
    FROM labs
    WHERE lab_id = NEW.lab_id;
    IF students_class_id <> labs_class_id THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = error_message;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

This trigger invokes automatically when a user tries to insert a new allotment for a student and validates the entry. If `student_id` and `lab_id` does not belong to same class, then an error message is displayed, restricting its entry.